# Stream not in sync with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, yolo

I am using an [implementation of YOLOv4](https://github.com/ceccocats/tkDNN) to detect traffic from a stream.

However because the hardware is a little bit slower than the 25 FPS of the stream, it stays behind it about 2 seconds. This means that i get two seconds jumps repeatedly throughout the detection process.

Is there a way for the OpenCV to read the stream sequentially, even when it is not synced?

Thanks

Comment: Save frames to buffer in one thread and feed them to yolo in another